# how to determine keyboard disconnected in DirectInput

Tags: c++, winapi, directinput

I am monitoring HID connections using EnumDevices(..., DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY).  When I disconnect a game controller it no longer shows up in the callback.  However, when I disconnect the keyboard, it still shows up in EnumDevices.

I've looked through the API, but I don't see where else to query if a device is connected.

Comment: Does it happen often that users disconnect keyboards while using your application? ;-)

Comment: My application will capture all keyboard state and will replicate it on non-PC platforms.  This includes connect and disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can subscribe to any device notifications like attach,detach,etc...

Comment: Since I am a console application, I don't have a message processing loop.  Is there another alternative, or is there a simple way to add a message loop to a console application.