# Is there a way to see if a physical keyboard is attached to a Windows 8 device?

Tags: windows-8

I'm writing a Windows 8 game.  The game runs on Windows 7, Windows Phone, and XBox.

I want to display keyboard hints if a keyboard is attached (e.g. 'Press Esc to exit')

Seeing as Windows 8 can be a desktop, laptop, or tablet, there may or may not be a physical keyboard attached. Is there a way to determine this programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect keyboard presence in Windows 8 desktop program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993680/detect-keyboard-presence-in-windows-8-desktop-program)

Comment: It's not a dupe as this is for Store Apps, it's relevant however given people are bound to want this for Desktop apps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course,
please read this quick start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868250)

```
private void GetKeyboardProperties()
{
    KeyboardCapabilities keyboardCapabilities = new Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
    KeyboardPresent.Text = keyboardCapabilities.KeyboardPresent != 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

or if you html5/js developer take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465379).

Comment: how do i access this in VS2012 .net 2?

Comment: FYI this only applies to Windows Store apps. You won't have access to this API if you're running on the regular desktop.

Comment: You do have access from Desktop apps if you reference `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`, the API is not restricted to store app containers. But it doesn't work correctly anyways, it reports as 'Yes' on a surface 4 pro tablet if there is no keyboard attached.