# Is it possible to detect when tablet screen is detached on hybrid laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, tablet, gesture, touchscreen

We are performing a pilot program testing how users utilize a Dell Windows 8 Hybrid laptop with our software.  We would like some way to track how often and when users disconnected their touch screen from the keyboard base and how long they used it in this mode, what actions they performed, and what sort of gestures they used while detached, etc.

Any pointers would be great!  If there is something exposed by .NET we could write our own app for or if there is a third party tool that does this tracking already, either one could be a solution.

Comment: If it's a metro app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113118/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-a-physical-keyboard-is-attached-to-a-windows-8-device

Comment: I think it has to be provided by DELL, in Windows system or .NET framework there is no such thing since this feature is specific to a very few models. DELL could plant a hardware sensor in the system that can be utilized to _switch mode_, better contact DELL support first.

Comment: I'd assume that the touch display is connected through regular USB ports. You can use [USBView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019.aspx) to verify this. If this turns out to be the case, you can subscribe to USB hardware change notifications.