# How to check programatically if keyboard is connected or not?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-4.0, pinvoke

I am developing an application with C# winforms.

Our application is going to be installed on win8 surface(touch screen device).

We want to check if a keyboard is connected via USB then our app will not show soft keypad otherwise it will show.

Many methods are avaliable to check for WinRT but none for winforms C#.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CallumLinington we have tried this but it shows list of keyboards registered with machine does not provide event if keyboard connected or not.Thanks

Comment: These questions seem to be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930958/win32-determining-when-keyboard-is-connected-disconnected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993680/detect-keyboard-presence-in-windows-8-desktop-program

Comment: It may be related but I am using C#

Comment: I guess you finally will have to use P/Invoke.

Comment: Partially off-topic but [the default keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/touch-cover-the-touch-keyboard) for surfaces don't connect via usb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just wrote this and tested on W8:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name from Win32_Keyboard");

        foreach(ManagementObject keyboard in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (!keyboard.GetPropertyValue("Name").Equals(""))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("KB Name: {0}", keyboard.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
            }
        }
```

I also connected a second keyboard and can see it detected. When I unplug one I get one entry, when unplug both I get nothing.

I also found some examples here: 
[Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7365/Retrieving-Hardware-Information-in-C)
and here [Example 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/29d7e0/get-the-key-board-details-of-your-system-in-windows-form/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way we can get event of keyboard connect/disconnect?

Comment: Did this really work? Afaik windows 8 tablets will always register as having 1 keyboard regardless of if they have a physical or not (the Surface 3 at least), or have i misunderstood something?

Comment: @Snellface, I've resolved the issue by checking for the USB value.  Please see my answer.

Comment: will a bluetooth keyboard appear as a physical keyboard? Or the old bus connected keyboards? We really need a way to determine if there is a physical keyboard or just a virtual one.

Answer (score 4):

To determine if it is connected via USB, check for that string:

```
private readonly string USB = "USB";

    private bool GetKeyboardPresent()
    {
        bool keyboardPresent = false;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Keyboard");

        foreach (ManagementObject keyboard in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData prop in keyboard.Properties)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(prop.Value).Contains(USB))
                {
                    keyboardPresent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }      
        }

        return keyboardPresent;
    }
```

Or you could instead potentially use this Powershell command:

```
PS C:\Users\myUserID> Get-WmiObject Win32_Keyboard
```

Comment: How does this work for laptops that have an embedded keyboard?