# How do I programmatically set "Display on-screen keyboard when no keyboard is connected?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

In Windows 11, there is the option "Keyboard" -> "Show virtual keyboard if not physical keyboard is attached" in the system settings.

I would like to know how I could turn this setting on / top or get its status using an API or any other programmatic way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods

1. Using .NET API check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28472434/6894386

---

2. Using command-line tools and batch script.

- Command to get a list of keyboards connected (*change 'hid' to 'usb' for physical USB connected). (It will also show any USB dongle if it's a mouse.*)

**Command**
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "Get-CimInstance win32_keyboard | Where Description -match 'hid' | Format-Table description, pnpDeviceID -AutoSize -Wrap"`

**Output**
`description         pnpDeviceID`
`HID Keyboard Device HID\{00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_VID&000204E8_PID&7021&COL01\8&2051871A&13&0000`
`HID Keyboard Device HID\CONVERTEDDEVICE&COL01\5&353EC129&0&0000`

- To start the on-screen keyboard, use the following command.
  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\osk.exe`
  Combining these two commands, you can write a batch file to start OSK if the keyboard is not present in the list. And add that file to
  `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` this folder